# Could this specific edit to the registry to fix UI scaling be harmful?

Tags: virus, safe-browsing-filter

I found this tutorial on how to fix UI scalling problems on high resolution screens. The tutorial tells me to edit the registry editor to that the computer runs some code that i have to copy from the site. Since i'm not that good at computer-stuff i can't tell if it will harm my computer.

I have to add a DWORD (32 bit) value with the title PreferExternalManifest and a value of 1 decimal to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > SideBySide string in the registry editor.
Then i have to make a notepad-file with the title of the program + .manifest (example photoshop.exe.manifest) then i have to make the content of the notepad some code that i have to copy from the site.
This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*">
    </assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
      version="9.0.21022.8"
      processorArchitecture="amd64"
      publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
    </assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel
        level="asInvoker"
        uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>

<asmv3:application>
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>

</assembly>
```

Link to site: http://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/

Comment: This is a broad and vague question. If you do not trust à site or recognize your lack of expertise you should ask a technician in a computer store to do it for you.

Comment: Here's [a better explanation](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-fix-apps-that-look-small-on-high-dpi-and-high-resolution-displays/) of what's going on with this XML.

Comment: Okay so i just tried to follow the tutorial. It works like a charm and nothing bad have happened to my computer (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this file is fine. It is a Application Manifest that tells Windows that a program has no support for high-resolution displays.
Application Manifests are used to tell Windows about certain capabilities or requirements for a program.

The registry key is used to override any internal manifest files that are embedded in the program executable.

**Important:** If there is already a .manifest file beside the program executable (e.g. photoshop.exe.manifest for Photoshop) don't delete or change it. Or at least make a backup of this file before tinkering.

Details:

The first two `<dependency>` blocks are references to two common Windows libraries. Without these the program may no function correctly. (If there is no .manifest file Windows assumes these two are necessary)

The `<trustInfo>` block says that the program does not require elevated privileges and should be run with the same rights as the user that started it.

The `<application>` block tells Windows that the application was written without support for different DPI settings.

More Info on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is "written" in XML, this is not a programmation language and is used to format data : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language

I'm not an expert, but I don't think it can hurt your computer, however before writing in your Windows register I suggest you to save a copy in case it's going wrong.

Comment: XML is "only" data, but data can have far reaching consequences, depending where it ends up. Registry settings may e.g. affect what program to run when you double click a file of a certain type (starting a flash app when you click a text file), or what programs to autostart at log in, or change the security setting in your web browser.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I didn't precise that, old trojan were often adding a register key to start up automatically for example.